# Add views to "more" tab item

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to change appearence of "more" item in TabBarController? For example can I add custom views and change layout of tableView containing "more" controllers list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find it was already discussed in

[Customizing the More menu on a Tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2399024

So we can get instance of this "More" ViewController using:

```
UIViewController *moreViewController = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController;
```

In fact it is of undocumented class UIMoreListController declared as:

```
@interface UIMoreListController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

moreViewController.view property contain UITableView and we can use it, for example add tableHeaderView:

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView*)moreViewController.view;
moreTableView.tableHeaderView = myOwnCustomView;
```

But I am not sure is this code "applesafe"? Because it use private class although not explicitly. 
And what if I want to add a view that shouldn't scroll with table? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is all possible, if you could give us an example of what you want, maybe with a screenshot or something, then we can help you with some code examples

Comment: mm... How can it be more clear? Just add a custom UIView to automatically created UIViewController with list of controllers at "more" tab item.

Comment: btw are you using NIB files or are you building the whole thing using code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want to do...

by using UITableViewController as a moreview tabbaritem.

and can create a moreview some what similar to the standard moreView controller.