# Can a tab bar configuration view be customized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with 8 tabbar items in the tabbar controller.

Is there a way I can customize the layout of the "... (more)" view in which you can configure which tab bar items should appear in the main tab bar.

It seems to be a table view controller but i'd like to use custom cell views and a background image.

Comment: I took a look around StackOverflow and the answer appears here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar/439824#439824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar/439824#439824) : you can achieve a good level of customization by using a custom UITabBarController class and changing the datasource for the moreNavigationController's tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-uitabbarcontroller-how-to-save-user-customized-tab-order/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your post is very interesting but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. 

What I want to customize is the visual appearance of the page : I don't want a black & white table view but something prettier. I'm afraid this can't be done with the Apple SDKS that have been released so far...