# Change the color of moreNavigationController's icons

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I've managed to change the navBar tint, the background color and labels' color using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar).

**But is it possible to change the icons' color?**

(those left to tableview's labels)

Thanks!

[image: My half-done work]

Comment: Is editing the images an option?

Comment: Changing png color doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you referring to the tab bar icons or the table view cell images?

Comment: to the table view cell images

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar/439824#439824 ?

Comment: Yes i've read it. it was this that made me able to change labels' color and the background color. But unfortunately they don't speak about icons' color

Comment: What icons are you talking about? The only icons I see are in the tab bar at the bottom, but you say you want to change the icons for the table view cells? Do you mean images that would be displayed on the left or right side of each item in the table view?

Comment: Oh, I see there are those detail disclosure chevrons on the right side of the tableview cells. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Charlie: icons i'm speaking about are left to tableview's labels

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing, wish there was an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a way to change the icon colors, but I don't really think all this hacking is necessary anyway - [Apple certainly doesn't recommend it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW12).

As far as I can tell, there is nothing special about the moreViewController, apart from being hard to customize. If it were me, I'd simply create my own custom viewcontroller, say MoreViewController, as a subclass of UITableViewController, add it to a NavigationController and then add that as the fifth and last item in the TabBarController. This table would then have a cell for each additional viewcontroller that I'd like to show. Then I'd be free to customize these cells to my heart's content.

Comment: As a sidenote, through over two years of using iOS apps, I've yet to actually use any functionality hidden by a "More" button. I'd highly recommend reconsidering your GUI and trying to find a way to keep it at five tabs at the most. Or perhaps even reconsidering how much functionality you are stuffing into the app at all.

Comment: I've seen cases where it makes sense. For instance, on News apps, you might want a tab per "topic", and through the More button you can choose which are your favorite topics to always keep one tap away, using the more button to get to the others. I'd say this is applicable to most apps where you basically just want to consume one type of content, and then use the tabs to separate them by a "sub-type". However, I have to agree that the app presented here doesn't look like that kind of app...

Comment: This is a lame answer, there's plenty of good reasons to use the more controller.

Comment: I also recommend this route. I recently ran into an issue where I was using SplitViewControllers through the tab bar, but items under the more controller no longer work as SplitViewControllers. The only solution was building a custom TabBarController.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, nevertheless I'll post a fairly reasonable solution I found.

I first tried setting the global tint color to what I wanted, but that didn't work. Luckily, simply changing the tint color of the table view *did* work. Adapting code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438514/565857):

```
let color: UIColor
// ...
if let moreTableView = moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {
    moreTableView.tintColor = color
}
```

This still doesn't seem to affect the edit view controller, however.

**EDIT:**
There is actually a simpler way to do both, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29250582/565857).