# How to change UITabbarController's More ViewControllers UITableViewCells images?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

More `viewcontroller` images are showing up in default blue background instead on original images. I want to change them to original images and also want to increase `UITableViewCell's` height. 
I have tried implementing tableview delegate methods on `UITabbarController`, but nothing working out.
Even `moreNavigationController` is also not changing. 
1) Where do i have to write these custom methods `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Also `shouldSelectViewController` is not getting called. First time when i select a tabbar item it is being called and when i select the more item it is not getting called.
2) Where should i implement `UITableView` delegate methods.

My screen - 
[image: My screen looks like this, but i want]

required screen -

[image: something like the below screen]

A solution using swift is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this solution :http://stackoverflow.com/a/6019217/3901620

Comment: another also : http://stackoverflow.com/a/438514/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks. Thankyou for the link. I did not try with custom viewcontroller. I will try and get back. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the requirement working. The step wise procedure I followed is

1. Take a ViewController which extends UITabbarController.
2. Take an array with five elements exactly.(If more than five then default More functionality gets enabled).
3. First four tabs as required and fifth should be 'More' tab. With required tab images.
4. For 'More' tab create a View Controller which extends UITableView delegates and datasources. And implement respective methods of delegate and datasources.
5. Take an array of the Cells you want to display and display them.
6. Link this 'More' View Controller to the 'More' tab.
7. Change the images in tableview in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
   Run the application and check by selecting 'More' tab. This time it should show the changed UI.
   When each cell should show different View Controllers on selecting the cells, then segue to different view controllers using the segues from ViewController (Not segue from the tablecell). Define a unique segue id for each segue and show the viewcontrollers based on switch or ifelse conditions in shouldSelectViewController using performSegueWithIdentifier.

Thanks @KKRocks for the valuable links.

Answer (score 0):

There's some content to be unpacked here. I am not entirely certain I fully understand the question but I'll go ahead and reply partially as best I can.

**ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear**

You add code in `viewDidLoad` for initialization. This method will run when your view is originally loaded and unless you're instantiating the controller every time it will only run once ( in this case you dont because you're using the prebuilt tabbar system which takes care of that for you)

So I would add the styling code in `viewDidLoad()`

When a viewController is to be displayed, `viewWillAppear()` will be called. This will happen every time so if you need to perform repetitive tasks like network calls, restyling based on some other data, refreshing your tables, you should do it here.

**Table methods**

For doing whatever you need to do with a table you will most likely need both `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` to your view controller. Look up any UITableView tutorial online they're many very comprehensive and will explain how to add all the table methods you need in your viewController.

Comment: In CustomTabBarController which is a subclass on UITabBarController i have extended it to with UITableView Delegate and DataSources. Then i have implemented all the methods that are present. But nothing is getting called. My question is can i extend TabBarController with TableView controller? Or should i take a new ViewController subclass of UITableViewController to be displayed in 'More' tabbar item?