# How to set badge value for my 6th tab bar item?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to set the badge value on my 6th tabbaritem ?? How to do that.
I am able to set the badge value on 4th tabbaritem using self.tabbaritem.badgevalue=@""

But using the same principle I am unable to set the badge to my 6th tabbaritem. Please help me???

The following code contains my badge value.

```
            CustomBadge *customBadge1=[[CustomBadge alloc]init];

            customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:[self getBadges]
                                              withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor] withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] withBadgeFrame:YES withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                                    withScale:1.0 withShining:YES];

            [customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-customBadge1.frame.size.width/4,20, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];

            [self.view addSubview:customBadge1];
```

Comment: is this a iPhone or an iPad app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not have 6th tab in a Tabbar, as it goes against the deign rules set by Apple.

As this would result in showing up of the More button as the 5th button. On clicking this would redirect to table view which would show the 5th and 6th tab Views on which you cant set the badge to.

Comment: Actually i have my views in more taabbaritem.

Comment: The More button added to the TabBar is a functionality of the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and not the tab bar itself. The UITabBarController has a tab bar, and adds behaviour such as the More button, the Edit and all the fancy stuff that you see in most TabBased Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question -- if your tab bar supports editing, you can re-order the tabs while running, with tabs moving between the first 4 positions and the "more" controller.  (The 5th position is reserved for "More...").

Only the first 4 items have an actual UITabBarItem which is where the badge goes.  To support having a badge associated with the 6th thing, you could override the tab editing functions, call their [super] methods, then check to see if the re-ordered items should have badges.  If so, set their value.

This would, of course, require that you keep track of the badge values for the "more" items, in order to set them when they are shown.

You could also override/extend the "more" controller behavior to show the badge values in the table rows, perhaps next to the accessory indicator.

See this answer for pointers:
[Customizing the More menu on a Tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar)