# iOS - How to change color of icons in tab bar moreViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I want to change color of icons (and probably badge) in `moreNavigationController` from gray to something else.

I've read and successfully changed color of background and text. I did this by "replacing" data source of `moreViewController` (described e.g. here [Customizing the More menu on a Tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar) ). But updating icons (also textLabel value) here makes no effect. Is it possible to change this gray color to white (or anything else)? Or I have to implement my own `tabBarController`? (any good tutorials?)

PS. I know how to change icons on tab bar itself, the question is how to do this in `moreViewController`?

Thanks!
Piotr

Comment: You would have to create your own custom Tab Bar, if you want to customise the more button..

Comment: This is not possible without customization.

Comment: @V.J. Replacing only moreViewController is not an option? I know that this is read-only property, but maybe there is some kind of trick to do this?

Comment: No dude. I did the R&D before 20 days for my application but didn't find anything which is going to be helpful to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from long research on the web and answers in this thread, it seems that it is not possible on iOS7 to change color of the icons (gray color) displayed in `moreViewController` of `UITabBarController`. The best solution for customizable tab bar is to implement it (or use some library).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case it is still relevant to anyone.
You can change icon colors displayed in a tableView of moreViewController:

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Changing a title is like so:

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "MyString"
```

Changing Edit button:

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the appearance proxy, new in iOS 5. In your app delegate's didFinishLaunching method:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
In iOS 7 use:

[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

See the UITabBar class reference for more details.

Comment: Appearance proxy seems to work only in tab bar itself. My point is to change color in view that is displayed after you click "more" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color, just subclass the tab bar controller and in it's view did load add the below code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var view = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view as UITableView
    view.tintColor = Utilities.mainColor()
    view.separatorStyle = .None
  }
```

For more you can see my question here : [Change tint color of tabbar edit view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29248656/468724)