# Change tint color of tabbar edit view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to change the tint color for the Edit view controller of tab bar controller. I have managed to change the color for more view controller but not getting clue for this.

This code was to change the color of more view controller, written in `UITabBarController`'s subcalss

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var view = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view as UITableView
    view.tintColor = Utilities.mainColor()
    view.separatorStyle = .None
  }
```

#### Suggestions are welcomed for both Objective-C or Swift

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to set global tint color is set AppDelegate.window.tintColor.

Comment: try using this `self.moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = Utilities.mainColor();` instead of applying tint on `topViewController`

Comment: @Zahid it doesn't work, it just changes the tint color of MoreViewController not the edit vc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By trying below code worked for me

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //this line helped me
    self.view.tintColor = Utilities.mainColor()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set manually coloured images for `tabBarItem`.

```
UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sports"];
defaultImage = [defaultImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];//system tints wont apply on the default image
UIImage *selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"sports"] imageWithColor:tintColor];
selectedImage = [selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];//System tints wont apply on this image
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sports" image:defaultImage selectedImage:selectedImage];
        }
```

Following function can be used to tint image manually

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color1
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    [color1 setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```