# Customise more view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have total 9 tab bar items each and every tab bar item is associated with a `UIViewController`. After 4 tab bar items, the other 5 go under `More` as it should be. Now I couldn't find a way to customise that `More Screen` (see image below). Please help me. Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController * moreNavControl = tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
```

Now you can change the appearance of the Navigation bar

```
moreNavControl.navigationBar.barStyle
```

You can get tableview object like this and after that do what ever operation  you want to do with tableview..

```
UITableView *tblView = (UITableView *)moreNavControl.topViewController.view;
```